# Change volume of SoundEffect Class

Tags: c#, .net, monogame

I have initialized a SoundEffect property like so:

```
private SoundEffect sound;
```

and it has been loaded in the `Load()` function like so:

```
sound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Jump15");
```

The sound plays fine, however it is too loud, and I've tried using `SoundEffect.MasterVolume` in the `Load()` function with different values but it doesn't seem to be changing the volume at all.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a version of the [`SoundEffect.Play()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904205.aspx) method that takes volume as a parameter. You can set the second and third arguments to zero.

```
sound = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("Jump15");
sound.Play(volume: 0.5f, pitch: 0.0f, pan: 0.0f);
```

Alternately you can create a sound effect instance and set the volume after the sound starts playing. This can be useful when you want to apply effects, like fading the sound in or out.

```
var instance = sound.CreateInstance();
instance.Volume = 0.5f;
instance.Play();
```

For more information, [here's a nice tutorial](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/playing-sound-effects) on playing `SoundEffect`s in XNA/MonoGame.

Comment: I used the tutorial instead, and works perfectly, thank you!